# How to generate a value for sorting similar text phrases?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, text

I have a list of texts which are required to be sorted by similarity, based on a value exclusively obtained from the text itself. Hence, no comparison allowed as it could take too long to compare with thousands of other texts.

The idea is to generate values (numeric or not), from arbitrary text phrases, like in the next example:

```
42334220 = "A white horse is running accross the field"
42334229 = "The white horse is running across that field"
42334403 = "A white animal is running across the green field"
```

Notice that the first and second phrases are together because they're more similar than the last, plus despite both start with the same letter.

I have used, in other scenarios, the [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) function, but it is oriented to pronuntiation, for single words and dependant on the first letter.

So, how to generate (aka what algorithms exists for classify) that exemplified value which represents a phrase for sorting purposes?

Comment: how are you defining similarity?

Comment: Is there a bound we can assume on length of a text phrase?

Comment: What I call "similar" is just my human common sense, that the algorithm creator should define, I think.

Comment: The text limit for a phrase, should be something between 50 to 100 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at fourier transformation. This is successfully applied to find similarities in images or audio samples. I think it could be well-suited for your problem.

- You could view a String as int array, i.e. a signal function from position => char value
- Do a fourier transform on this function
- return a sublist of k indexes of highest elements in the result (greater k means greater precision)

Perhaps the signal function has to be adjusted to get a better match to the common understanding of similarity:

- use a function position => word-index (look up the word in a dictionary and get its index)
- use a function position => ngram-index (= weighted sum of the n chars)
- if the sequence of words is not of relevance, use a function char -> frequency of the character (ordered alphabetically)

Maybe other transforms (e.g. wavelet transform) would do better.

Comment: Great idea! I will investigate further.